# How to use a method in a Master Page from a Content Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I am writing an ASP.NET 4 application with C#. I have a Master Page, inside of which I have the following method:

```
public void DisplayMessage(string input)
{
   Label myMessageDisplayer = (Label)FindControl("uxMessageDisplayer");
   myMessageDisplayer.Text = input;
}
```

Can I call this method from a content page?
At the moment, I use in Content Page this code:

```
Master.DisplayMessage("Item has been inserted.");
```

And I receive this error:

> 'System.Web.UI.MasterPage' does not contain a definition for 'DisplayMessage' and no extension method 'DisplayMessage' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.MasterPage' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Which VS version are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use casting to get your master page type, as others have shown, or you can add the [`MasterType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228274.aspx) directive to your page markup (at the top, where the standard `<%@ Page %>` directive is):

```
<%@ MasterType TypeName="YourNamespace.YourMasterPageType" %>
```

Then in your page code, you can have just what you have in your example:

```
Master.DisplayMessage("Item has been inserted.");
```

The `MasterType` directive is available from .NET 2 upwards.

Comment: "The MasterType directive is available from .NET 2 upwards."   As are Master Pages.  :-)

Answer (score 6):

You need to cast the `Master` to the actual Masterpage type

```
// MyMasterPage is the type of your masterpage
((MyMasterPage)Master).DisplayMessage("Item has been inserted.");
```

You can also add a [MasterType directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228274.aspx) to the top of your content page to achieve the same thing:

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MyMasterPage.master" %>
```

Then you can use:

```
Master.DisplayMessage('Item has been inserted.');
```

Comment: Hi where I can inser <%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MyMasterPage.master" %>
 in the content page or master page? thanks

Comment: That's placed in the content page.

Comment: @GlbboK - add it to your content page. Then you can just use `Master.DisplayMessage('...');`

Comment: I try Graham, but i get an error again Error 1 The type or namespace name 'MasterPages' does not exist in the namespace 'WebProject.Web.Cms.AdminCms' (are you missing an assembly reference?)... what im doing wrong???

Comment: I am using this code: <%@ MasterType  virtualPath="~/Cms/AdminCms/MasterPages/AdminCms.Master"%>

Comment: @BlbboK - is the path to `AdminCms.Master` correct? Does it work without the MasterType directive and casting in your code to the correct type?

Comment: @BlbboK - Is this a website or web application project?

Comment: OK I made it, I have to fix just the path really thanks fot hits

Answer (score 0):

I made/try this:

My Control (MenuEsquerdo.ascx)

```
<%--<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Site.Master" %>--%>
<%--<%@  MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" %>--%>
<%--<%@ MasterType TypeName="Delivery.SiteMaster" %>--%>
<%--<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Site.Master" %>--%>
<%@ MasterType TypeName="Delivery.SiteMaster" %>
```

My Designer Control (MenuEsquerdo.ascx.designer.cs)

```
public new Delivery.SiteMaster Master {
            get {
                return ((Delivery.SiteMaster)(base.Master)); // 'System.Web.UI.UserControl' does not contain a definition for 'Master'
            }
        }
```

And my code behind (MenuEsquerdo.ascx.cs)

```
RepeaterListaMenuEsquerdoCtr.DataSource = this.Master.ClassMercadorias.Take(20);
RepeaterListaMenuEsquerdoCtr.DataBind();
```

**Know, how I can fix this: 'System.Web.UI.UserControl' does not contain a definition for 'Master'?**