# Access Master Page Method in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

How should I access public methods of master page from a child page?

**UserMaster.master.vb**

```
 Public Sub UpdateCart()
 End Sub
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

How can I access `UpdateCart()` from the Default.aspx.cs page?

Comment: Related: [How to use a method in a Master Page from a Content Page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5068521/3258851)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From you Content page you can use this to achieve the requirement and make sure it marked as a *public* not protected:

VB

```
TryCast(Me.Master, MyMasterPage).UpdateCart()
```

C#

```
(this.Master as MyMasterPage).UpdateCart();
```

Comment: Worked like a charm... :)

Answer (score 4):

Do it like this:

```
SiteMaster master = new SiteMaster();
//now call the master page method
master.test()
```

Example

```
//master page code behind
public partial class SiteMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    //test method
    public void test()
    {
    }

}

//content page code behind
public partial class About : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SiteMaster master = new SiteMaster();
        master.test();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or make the `SiteMaster` method `static` and just call it directly:

```
SiteMaster.MyStaticMethod()
```